# Minimum Maximum edge among all paths from source to destination

Tags: graph-theory

Needs to find out the minimum maximum of all edges in all paths from source and destination.
[image]

Here two paths possible from 1 to 6. in the top path maximum weight of the edge is 4. In the bottom path maximum weight of the edge is 6. So 4 is the answer. Can anybody suggest an optimized algorithm?

What i currently doing is taking all paths and calculating their maximum edge. After exploring all paths using DFS. I calculate the minimum of all max. But time complexity is O(v^v) Exponential.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem

Answer (score 0):

You are basically looking for the minimum distance where the length of a path is the maximum weight of its edges instead of the sum. Since the operation "maximum" shares a lot of properties with addition, e.g. it is increasing if you fix one term, it is commutative and associative, you can use the same algorithm to solve it (Dijkstra's algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

A small optimization from what you are doing.  You do not need to check every edge weight on every path.

```
- Use Dijkstra to find cheapest path ( sum of all weights on path )
- Find edge on Dijkstra path with greatest weight. Set best weight and best path
- Find all paths
- Iterate over paths
   - Iterate over edges in path
       - If edge weight greater then best weight
            - break out of loop over edges
       - If edge weight greater then max path weight
            - set max path weight
   - end loop over path edges
   - if max path weight less than best weight
      - update best weight and best path
- end loop over paths
- output best weight and best path
- STOP
```

Other than this, there is no further optimization possible

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative solution:

1. Sort the edges by their weights in the decreasing order
2. Keep removing edges until the source and destination becomes disconnected
3. Output the weight of the last removed edge

If we are free to choose the datastructure for storing the graph, then with a binary search for Step 2. the complexity should be `O(e log e)` where `e` is the number of edges in the graph.

Then Step 2. would be performed with with a graph search (DFS or BFS)  of complexity `O(e)` for every bisection. Here we just need to find the first index `i` in the array of sorted edges

`E[0], ... , E[e-1]`

such that  there is no path using only the edges in

`E[i+1], ... , E[e-1]`

between  the source and destination.